# VBA to open the first link in the Outlook email then the next link

Tags: vba, email, excel, hyperlink, outlook

Please advise me on parts of this or the whole thing if possible. I basically have an email every morning with 5-8 links to reports (on Sharepoint) and have to click each one, which then opens an excel document with the report, click refresh all, save then go back to outlook and click the next link. Is there a way to open the first link in Outlook, go to excel refresh all, save, then go back to Outlook and open the next link and repeat until all links have been pressed in VBA? Any and all help is greatly appreciated, Thank you.

```
Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application

Set objApp = Application
On Error Resume Next
Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
    Case "Explorer"
        Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Case "Inspector"
        Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
End Select

Set objApp = Nothing
End Function

Sub Hyperlink(itm As MailItem)
Dim bodyString As String
Dim bodyStringSplitLine
Dim bodyStringSplitWord
Dim splitLine
Dim splitWord

bodyString = itm.Body
bodyStringSplitLine = Split(bodyString, vbCrLf)

For Each splitLine In bodyStringSplitLine
    bodyStringSplitWord = Split(splitLine, " ")

    For Each splitWord In bodyStringSplitWord
        splitWord.Hyperlink.Select
    Next
Next
Set itm = Nothing
End Sub

Sub test()
Dim currItem As MailItem
Set currItem = GetCurrentItem
Hyperlink currItem
End Sub
```

This is what I have come up with so far. Definitely contains errors. I just run the sub test() in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a .Follow in Word.

```
Sub Hyperlink(itm As mailitem)

Dim oDoc As Object
Dim h As Hyperlink

If itm.GetInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then

    Set oDoc = itm.GetInspector.WordEditor

    For Each h In oDoc.Hyperlinks
        Debug.Print h.Name
        If Right(h.Name, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
            h.Follow
        End If
    Next

End If

Set oDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class to handle all incoming emails. Then in the event handler you can parse the [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) property value and extract links. Then you can do whatever you need with links - open them in the browser and etc.

I'd recommend starting from the  [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article in MSDN. Then you may find a lot of HOWTO articles in the [Concepts (Outlook 2013 developer reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868025(v=office.15).aspx) section.

Comment: I got a basic understanding, but what is the command or object type to select and loop through links?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a bit too large, and although not too difficult, it involves multiple object library references (Regular Expressions, Internet Explorer, Excel). It is unlikely you that you will get a full solution to your problem. VBA is a really powerful and cool scripting language and not too difficult to learn. I highly recommend you divide your problem into smaller tasks, and try to work each task separately and come back with more specific questions.