# how to automatically trigger a link in outlook email using VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm trying to programmatically click on a link which creates an email with predefined subject,to,cc,bcc and body content of the email.My requirement is, If I select an Outlook mail item and click on “Approve via mail” in my Addin, the code will search for hyperlink “Click here to Approve” in the mail body and Automatically click on the hyperlink.
The hyperlink “Click here to Approve” creates an email with predefined subject,to,cc,bcc and body content of the email.
I'm not sure how to do it with VSTO as all the other solutions suggest using JQuery and Javascript

```
Object selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
        Outlook._MailItem eMail = (Outlook._MailItem)
        this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        eMail = ((Outlook._MailItem)selObject);
        if(eMail.HTMLBody.Contains("Approve"))
        {

        }
```

I'm not sure what I can write in the IF segment of the code.Please Suggest.

Comment: Try this answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111291/vba-to-open-the-first-link-in-the-outlook-email-then-the-next-link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook doesn't provide anything for opening hyperlinks. You can use the the following code ([Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) for opening them in the default web browser:

```
Process.Start("your_hyperlink");
```

Or just create a Mail item progrmmatically in Outlook based on the info where the Approve button was clicked.

```
 Outlook.MailItem mail = null;
Outlook.Recipients mailRecipients = null;
Outlook.Recipient mailRecipient = null;
try
{
    mail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
       as Outlook.MailItem;
    mail.Subject = "A programatically generated e-mail";
    mailRecipients = mail.Recipients;
    mailRecipient = mailRecipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev");
    mailRecipient.Resolve();
    if (mailRecipient.Resolved)
    {
        mail.Send();
    }
    else
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
            "There is no such record in your address book.");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
        "An exception is occured in the code of add-in.");
}
finally
{
    if (mailRecipient != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailRecipient);
    if (mailRecipients != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailRecipients);
    if (mail != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail);
}
```

Take a look at the following articles for more information and samples:

- [How to create and show a new Outlook mail item programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/26/outlook-create-show-message-programmatically/)
- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)
- [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)
- [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer..but the hyperlink is just a new email window with Auto populated Subject Line, Bcc, CC and To options..and for me there is no way to know all these fields..That is why I was thinking if there is any other way